# mvn install compilation error package java.time does not exist

Tags: java, maven

running mvn install and getting compilation error,

```
package java.time does not exist
```

However, I'm running java 1.8.  What could I be missing?

Comment: Let's check your JAVA_HOME environment variable by command: `echo %JAVA_HOME%` to see where is the true java version you are using? If you are using an IDE like eclipse, please check your project setting if you are using java compiler version 1.8

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21

Comment: You see, you are using java version 1.7. If you have already installed java 1.8 then change your JAVA_HOME to the jdk 1.8

Comment: Actually I have JRE 1.8 and JDK1.7 as mentioned.  Should I point environment variable to JRE instead of JDK?

Comment: No, you must have JDK 1.8 and point JAVA_HOME to this JDK

Comment: No the error switched to tools.jar not found.

Comment: Uninstall the old jdk then install the new one, then set the JAVA_HOME to the new jdk and also set the path to %JAVA_HOME%\bin